# JS to change inner html table cell

Tags: javascript, php, function, dom-events, innerhtml

I am self taught PHP with little js experience so it is probably something really simple, but I have made a js function to change the inner html of a table cell and added an `onchange` event listener on a select element to call the function. However nothing happens when I change the selected value and I have no idea why, considering it is so simple it should. Please help.

td that I want to change:

```
        echo '<tr><td id="pastEvents">';
        for($i=0;$i<=3;$i++){
            echo '<table class="invisible"><tr><td><img src="/'.$pastEvents[$i]['banner'].'" alt="Event Banner"></td></tr><tr><td>'.$pastEvents[$i]['name'].'</td></tr></table>';
        }
        echo '</td></tr>';
```

Event Listener:

```
echo '<tr><td><table class="invisible"><tr><td>Number Shown: <select name="select" onchange="changePast()"><option value="3">3</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="all">All</option></select></td></tr></table></td></tr>';
```

Script:

```
<script>
    function changePast(){
        var shown = document.getElementsByName("select");
        document.getElementById("pastEvents").innerhtml = "test";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: try innerHTML instead of innerhtml

Comment: Whether to use `innerHTML` or not depends on what you want to do with `shown`, the `HTMLCollection` of all `select` elements you have assigned above the line with the erroneous `innerhtml`.

Comment: @Xufox I plan to add it to the for loop like so: ...innerHTML = "html/php"+shown+"html/php" however capitalizing the HTML hasn't seemed to fix the problem. Still nothing happens when I change the select box value

Comment: Yeah, `shown` is an `NodeList` (not `HTMLCollection` as stated previously, sorry). You need one specific element out of that. Then, assuming you mean to add the `value` of that `select` element, you need to get the `value` of it. Otherwise you’ll end up with `"[object NodeList]"` or `"[object HTMLSelectElement]"`.

Comment: Is there any error shown in your browser console? Can you try adding a `console.log('test');` at the start of your function to see whether anything happens at all?

Comment: @Xufox it says in the browser: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null. I'm clueless

Comment: Is it a problem that I have used php to echo the <td id="...">

Comment: Oh, this means the element isn’t found. Which is weird, because you are indeed echoing it with PHP and the element is only ever accessed when you change the `select` dropdown because the `changePast` function is only executed in the `onchange` inline handler. Does the `<td id="pastEvents">` really exist in your document?

Comment: @Xufox It definately is in the document. The td is actually part of an invisible table inside another styled table. I remember seeing online somewhere an example of code where a getElementById() is stored in a var and then something like var.getElementById(). Would I maybe have to give the outer table an ID and go from there

Comment: @IVAOCA-WM That shouldn’t be necessary. The only mistake I can think of right now is the usage of the same ID multiple times… as long as your ID is unique in the document, this should actually work. If that’s not it, then the mistake most likely is not within the code you’ve shown us so far.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to use is .innerHtml() instead of .innerhtml()

```
<script>
    function changePast(){
        var shown = document.getElementsByName("select");
        document.getElementById("pastEvents").innerHtml = "test";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

actually it is **innerHTML**

```
<div id="A"></div>

document.getElementById("A").innerHTML = 'text'
```

Comment: It still doesn't work, not sure why but nothing happens when I change the select box value